# Hyperlinks in Django for loop are linking to the same page

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

On a user's profile page right now it is displaying the number of people they are following and the usernames of the people they are following. When the user clicks on a username, I quite simply want it to take the user to that user's profile page but right now it is linking back to the same user's profile page, so essentially just reloading the page.

I am guessing it is because I am passing in `user.username` as a keyword argument because when I follow this same format but instead using user.id I don't run into this problem. I would like to use `user.username` so that the username can be displayed in the url.

```
rofilePage.html
```

```
{% block body %}
<h3>{{ user.username }}</h3>
<br>
<br>

<p>{{ profile.number_of_friends }}</p>

<p>{% for friend in profile.get_friends %}</p>
    <a href="{% url 'profile' profile.user.username %}">{{ friend }}</a><br>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

`views.py`:

```
def profile_page(request, user_username):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=user_username)
    return render(request, "network/profilePage.html", {
        "profile": profile
    })
```

`urls.py`:

```
path("profile/<str:user_username>", views.profile_page, name="profile"),
```

`models.py`:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name='following', blank=True, symmetrical=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>{% for friend in profile.get_friends %}</p>
    <a href="{% url 'profile' profile.user.username %}">{{ friend }}</a><br>
{% endfor %}
```

You are iterating over friends but not mentioning it, should be `<a href="{% url 'profile' friend.user.username %}">{{ friend }}</a><br>`

Comment: That triggers a No reverse match error. `NoReverseMatch at /profile/poetry
Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<user_username>[^/]+)$']`

Comment: thank you because you were close and lead me down the correct path. Passing in the argument `friend.username` worked!

Answer (score 0):

{% for friend in profile.get_friends %}

is there a problem??
you are putting for in `<p>` tag?

try this:

```
{% for friend in profile.get_friends %}
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'profile' profile.user.username %}">{{ friend }}</a><br>
</p>    
{% endfor %}
```